# Looping through a file while skipping the blank rows

Tags: awk

I have a file in following format

```
value value 17 -1 1234 4567 value id1
value value 17 -1 2345 4580 value id1
value value 17 -1 2344 4654 value id1

value value 1 1 1234 4567 value id2
value value 1 1 3445 3455 value id2

value value 1 1 2341 2345 value id3
value value 1 1 1245 4567 value id3
value value 1 1 3234 5634 value id3
value value 1 1 3412 4512 value id3
```

I want to retrieve the following information for each group of lines between the blanks rows:

for eg for id1:

```
17 -1 1234 4654 id1
```

for id2:

```
1 1 1234 3455 id2
```

i.e for each id (last column) I would like to retrieve the 5 th column of the first line in that group and 6 th column of the last line in that group ( the lines are grouped by ids).

Comment: Could you make the pattern more explicit? There are 3 lines with 'id1' and 2 with 'id2'. How do the final id1 and id2 examples correspond to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may do the work for you

```
$ awk '/^$/{print col3, col4, col5, col6, idval; next} $8 != idval{idval = $8; col3=$3; col4=$4; col5=$5} {col6=$6} END{print col3, col4, col5, col6, idval}' input
17 -1 1234 4654 id1
1 1 1234 3455 id2
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`

```
awk -vRS= -vFS='\n' '{split($1, a, /[[:blank:]]+/);
split($NF, b, /[[:blank:]]+/); 
print a[3], a[4], a[5], b[6], a[8]}' file
17 -1 1234 4654 id1
1 1 1234 3455 id2
1 1 2341 4512 id3
```

Comment: Are you shure you need `gnu` for `RS` without data

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk -vRS= '{print $3,$4,$5,$(NF-2),$8}' file
17 -1 1234 4654 id1
1 1 1234 3455 id2
1 1 2341 4512 id3
```

This divide every block to one record, then print field 3,4,5 third-last and 8

Comment: I think this is the best way +1, this is gawk only though, might want to mention that :)

Comment: @Jidder I know that using multiple character in `RS` is a `gnu` option.  But can you point me to documentation that using nothing is `gnu` also.

Comment: `Almost all other awk implementations20 store strings internally as C-style strings. C strings use the NUL character as the string terminator. In effect, this means that ‘RS = "\0"’ is the same as ‘RS = ""’. (d.c.)` So that would read the whole file in as a single record on some awks(i think anyway).